# Mark on Vishnu's chest

Tags: shiva, vishnu

Mahabharata Bibek Debroy translation p 4861:

> Hari, the
> lord of the universe, spoke to the god Ishana. ‘He who knows you, knows me.
> He who follows you, follows me. There is no difference between you and me.
> Do not think otherwise. Your spear will leave the srivatsa mark on my chest.
> My hand will leave a beautiful mark on your throat, to be known as
> shrikantha.’1278 They thus left marks on each other.

There are of course other explanations of Siva's blue throat.

Do all scriptures say there is a mark on Vishnu's chest and are there other explanations for it?

Comment: the srivatsa maru (aka mole) is where sri lakshmi devi resides. this is mentioned in vamana avatar where he has to hide the mark (otherwise it will belie the fact that he is married to Sri, but he has to play role of brahmachari) with the deer skin (krishnajina).

Comment: some addition to mar's point. Sri Lakshmi resides in Shrivatsava and whenever someone wants to donate something it is said Sri Lakshmi would hide and see them donate so she peeped out to see Bali, Sukhracharya sees it and comes to know that the person who has come is no Bramachari

Answer (score 3):

Yes Bhagwan Sri Ram and Bhagwan Sri Krishna, Sri Vamana also have Srivatsa symbol on their chest like Bhagwan Vishnu. It is said Vishnu's tenth avatar Kalki will also have the mark on him

> When Brahma Deva , along with other Gods had reached Lanka and had approached Bhagwan Sri Ram, he had called Bhagwan Sri Ram as Bhagwan Vishnu , the one who bears Srivatsa symbol on his chest.
> "The entire cosmos is your body. The earth constitutes your firmness. Fire is your anger. The moon constitutes your placidity. You are Lord Vishnu (who bears the mark Srivatsa - a curl of white hair on his chest)."

Source : Valmiki Ramayana Yuddha Kanda Sarga 117

Bhagwan Sri Ram is Bhagwan Vishnu himself, so its natural that he will have Srivatsa mark on his chest and moreover , if he did’nt have one, then Brahma Deva would never have mentioned about Srivasta mark at all.

> Bhagwan Sri Krishna too being Bhagwan Vishnu himself , had Srivatsa mark on his chest. This fact was confirmed by Maharishi Markandeya himself in the Vana Parva Markandeya Samasya Parva of Mahabharata.
> Markandeya continued, 'Having said so unto me that wonderful Deity vanished, O son, from my sight! I then beheld this varied and wondrous creation start into life. O king, O thou foremost of the Bharata race, I witnessed all this, so wonderful, O thou foremost of all virtuous men, at the end of the Yuga! And the Deity, of eyes large as lotus leaves, seen by me, in days of yore is this tiger among men, this Janardana who hath become thy relative! It is in consequence of the boon granted to me by this one that memory doth not fail me, that the period of my life, O son of Kunti, is so long and death itself is under my control. This is that ancient and supreme Lord Hari of inconceivable soul who hath taken his birth as Krishna of the Vrishni race, and who endued with mighty arms, seemeth to sport in this world! This one is Dhatri and Vidhatri, the Destroyer of all the Eternal, the bearer of the Sreevatsa mark on his breast, the Lord of the lord of all creatures, the highest of the high, called also Govinda! Beholding this foremost of all gods, this ever-victorious Being, attired in yellow robes, this chief of the Vrishni race, my recollection cometh back to me! This Madhava is the father and mother of all creatures! Ye bulls of the Kuru race, seek ye the refuge of this Protector!'

> Sri Lakshmi resides in Shrivatsava and whenever someone wants to donate something it is said Sri Lakshmi would hide and see them donate so she peeped out of Vishnu's chest to see Bali, Sukhracharya sees it and comes to know that the person who has come is no Bramachari.

Srivatsa is a curl of white hair ( Sri means Lakshmi and vatsa means living). Srivatsa is one the names of Vishnu given in Vishnu sahasranamam

I thank Sailesh Ruth from quora from giving evidences for Sri Krishna and Rama also had Shrivatsa mark on their chests